# Can I remove "teh" from the dictionary in Mac OSX Yosemite?

Tags: osx-yosemite, spell-check, dictionary

I've never had use of the word "teh". Not even certain it's actually a word beyond "Urban Dictionary" definitions.

However, "teh" is a common typo, hence the urban dictionary entry. And it is a typo I often make. I would like *spellchecker to actually fix* this typo. But for some reason my Mac thinks it's an actual word.

No, "teh" has not been added to the user dictionary -- (users/[acct]/Library/Spelling) -- I've checked.

However, every time "teh" occurs, there's no correction to the misspelling and using control-click doesn't present the standard correction options. I'm only presented with "look up teh".

This is annoying.

Is there a way to add a word to the spell checker in OS 10.10.5? Or to remove "teh" from the dictionary look up?

Or in more general terms..

Can the OSX dictionary be edited? I know words can be *added*, but can apparently existing "bad" words in the core dictionary be changed?

Can the MacOS Spell Checker be set to contain a specific correction based upon a user's common error?

Comment: 'teh' gets auto-corrected for me; which would make me think you've overridden it at some time in the past & it now accepts it as a word, [not that I actually know how to answer your question, sorry]

Comment: I would suspect that @Tetsujin In fact, I did. And figured I'd just have to live with it until my next clean install. But examining the user dictionary, it's not there. And I just did a clean install of OS10.10.5 this morning. 100% certain I haven't added "teh" as "approved" back to anything.

Comment: I thought there was the remote possibility it had been added to the system dictionary between Yosemite & El Capitan, but I just checked a Yosemite VM & it still auto-corrects there too.

Comment: hmm.. curious...